# Sub Query with group by returns more than 1 row Issue

Tags: mysql, query, group-by, subquery, count

I am facing the issue of subquery returns more than 1 row cause I am using group by in the subquery and outer query both to get the desired result.

This is my query

```
SELECT Count(*)                                       AS totalCat,
       attempted_questions.category_id_fk,
       (SELECT Count(*)
        FROM   attempted_questions
        WHERE  attempted_questions.correct = 1
        GROUP  BY attempted_questions.category_id_fk) AS correct
FROM   attempted_questions
GROUP  BY attempted_questions.category_id_fk
```

I want to get total questions count and total correct questions count from this table against the category, like this below result.

```
   Category   Total_Questions   Total_Correct
      1             4                 3
      2             3                 1
```

This above mentioned is the required result from my query but it is not working for me, I have tried to fix it but could not find any solution.

Please have a look at my attached image to see the database records and table structure.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the subquery to get "count of correct questions", you can get the same count using conditional aggregation utilizing [`CASE .. WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) statement with [`COUNT(..)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) in the main query itself:

```
SELECT category_id_fk AS category, 
       Count(*) AS total_questions,
       Count(CASE WHEN correct = 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS total_correct
FROM   attempted_questions
GROUP  BY category
```

[`COUNT(NULL)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) returns 0; so if an attempted question is not correct (`ELSE` condition against `WHERE correct = 1`), we return `NULL` to avoid counting it as correct.

---

Another possibility can be using [`SUM(..)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) with `CASE .. WHEN`. We can also utilize [MySQL's implicit typecasting of boolean to int](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html):

```
SELECT category_id_fk AS category, 
       Count(*) AS total_questions,
       SUM(correct = 1) AS total_correct
FROM   attempted_questions
GROUP  BY category
```

`correct = 1` returns either True or False for correct and incorrect questions, respectively. During `SUM(..)` operation on these boolean values, MySQL implicitly typecasts true to 1, and false to 0; thus giving us the desired count.

You can also write it in SQL standard way (by avoiding implicit typecasting), as follows:

```
SELECT category_id_fk AS category, 
       Count(*) AS total_questions,
       SUM(CASE WHEN correct = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS total_correct
FROM   attempted_questions
GROUP  BY category
```

The only difference with `COUNT(..)` approach here is that it we are returning `0` instead of `NULL` in the `ELSE` part for `SUM(..)`.